# is it possible to create a server side listbox control using javascript in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

how can i create a server side control like list box using javascript. is it possible ? Thank you. What i have done to create a dynamic list box is :

```
 for (j = 0; j < Data.Items.length; j++) {
                var Option = document.createElement("Option");
                var htmlSelect = document.getElementById("<%= LBox.ClientID %>");
                htmlSelect.options.add(Option);
                Option.text = Data.Items[j].Text;
                Option.value = Data.Items[j].Value;
            }
```

but it is not working fine . Any corrections? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Check link:

http://www.anujrohila.com/2013/05/how-to-access-server-side-listbox-using.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function AddItem() {
            var list = document.getElementById("<%=lbScriptAccess.ClientID %>");
            var option1 = document.createElement("option");
            option1.text ="Value" + list.length;
            option1.value = list.length;
            list.options.add(option1);
            return false;
        }
    </script>
```